# jQuery IE8 error on hide() function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I get the following Error:

> jquery1.4.2.js
>   Line: 2828
>   Error: The Object does not support the method.

My JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```

On FireFox it works like it should!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: perhaps try formatting that code a bit better.

Comment: Which line in your code causes the error?

Comment: IE8 Toolbar points at $(".tab_content").hide();

Comment: @phx - do an `alert(activeTab)` just after setting it, see what pops up.

Comment: @nick - alert is not been called.

Comment: @phx - Are you including any other libraries or anything?

Comment: Line 2828: `if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) != null && match[2] ) {` [in function: `Sizzle.filter`], what do you think @Nick, looks like it must be the variable `activeTab` when it gets passed in as a selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put a `debugger;` statement on the click event like so:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
    debugger;
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
```

You should then be able to step into the of you chose to do so on the popup.

Does it actually fail on the line that it says it does in your console?

Comment: workaround is to do appenClass('hidden'), works for me now.

Thanks for help!